# Is it valid and good practice to use vertical align and line height to center?

Tags: html, css

To vertically and horizontally align inline elements i use the following:

```
#parent {
display: table-cell; 
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
line-height: 100px;
}
```

Is this a good practice or considered to be a workaround? Should i feel bad doing this or is it going??

This will pass in the w3c validator but i feel that text-align and line-height are used in this case out of context as they should be used for text instead.

Comment: It's valid if you need it.

Comment: That's how you do if there's no more option.

Answer (score 2):

Inline elements and text are essentially the same thing in terms of CSS, so I don't see a problem with treating one like the other.

Even though `text-align` and its ilk were described as pertaining to text in the very beginning in CSS1, most CSS specifications these days don't make very concrete distinctions between inlines and text. Text itself is often even said to reside in anonymous inlines — see [section 9 of the CSS2.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html) for example — so you're technically still applying formatting to inlines either way.